# Collect all results from a Chan with getChanContents

Tags: haskell, concurrency, channel

I'm playing with [Channels](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html) in Haskell. I want to do some `IO` actions in parallel until one of them fails, then collect all the results into a list.

This code errors with `Exception <<loop>>`. How can I get it to work with `getChanContents`? All of the examples I've seen assume they know how many messages are on the channel.

Is there a cleaner way to collect a bunch of results from workers?

```
module UrlPatterns where

import Control.Concurrent
import Types
import Text.HTML.Scalpel
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Control.Concurrent.Chan
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Maybe (isJust, catMaybes)
import Data.List (takeWhile)


-- find all valid links under a domain that follow the pattern:
-- http://example.com/pages/(1..N)
-- as soon as one is missing, return a list of all the ones you found
findIncrementing :: URL -> IO [Link]
findIncrementing base = do

    let num = 1

    -- find channel
    cfind <- newChan
    writeChan cfind (base, num)

    -- results channel
    cdone <- newChan

    forkIO $ worker cfind cdone

    -- collect the results
    results <- getChanContents cdone
    let results = takeWhile isJust results :: [Maybe Link]
    print results

    return []


worker :: Chan (URL, Int) -> Chan (Maybe Link) -> IO ()
worker next done = loop
  where 
    loop = do
      (base, num) <- readChan next
      let url = pageUrl base num
      putStrLn $ "FETCHING: " <> url

      mt <- findPageTitle url

      case mt of
        Nothing -> do
          writeChan done Nothing
          putStrLn ("Missed " <> show num)
        Just t  -> do
          writeChan done $ Just $ Link url t
          writeChan next (base, num+1)

      loop

scrapeTitle :: Scraper String String
scrapeTitle = text "title"

findPageTitle :: URL -> IO (Maybe String)
findPageTitle url = scrapeURL url scrapeTitle

pageUrl :: URL -> Int -> URL
pageUrl base num = base <> show num
```

Comment: When you get `Exception <<loop>>`, it usually means you have written a recursive term in a `let` clause, such as `let results = takeWhile isJust results :: [Maybe Link]`.

Comment: Well... that explains why it wasn't working I guess :)  Seems like that should have been a compile-time error. One more lesson learned!

Comment: `getChanContents` may still be broken on GHC 7.10 as well, per this [bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9965)

Comment: It actually can't be a compile time error, as expressions such as this are perfectly valid : `let a = 1 : a`. But you should have had a compilation warning if compiled with `-Wall`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @bartavelle. I had an error unrelated to the channel code. Here's the relevant fix:

```
-- collect the results
results <- getChanContents cdone
let links = catMaybes $ takeWhile isJust results

return links
```